# Storing images as blobs in 2017?

Tags: mysql, blob, mariadb

I've found lots of different questions regarding this topic, but they are 6..maybe 10 years old.

Software continuously improves.. How does storing images as blobs (in MariaDB) perform and scale today? Is storing images as blobs a viable solution in latest MariaDB dbmss?

Comment: Why would it be viable, or better, than storing images in the filesystem and then only saving a URL reference into the DB?

Comment: Other considerations aside, images below 100k is fine.

Comment: What are you optimizing? Ultimately, database uses the file system. However, databases do a few other things, such as use RAM to cache working data set, deal with connections to clients (client can be another service such as `php-fpm`), so the question isn't about viability but about what you want to achieve. You can replicate databases easily, you can shard the tables, you can achieve faster reads due to this RAM caching - so what do you want to achieve really? Yes, it's viable. It was always viable. But, use the right tool for the job remains since 1970 - 2017 (and further).

Answer (score 0):

- MySQL and MariaDB have not changed in this area.
- Web page references to images have not changed.
- Spinning drives have been replaced by faster SSDs.
- Images have grown.

Still, the arguments about `BLOB` vs filesystem storage of images are mostly the same.